# Other function like FIND_IN_SET which returns number of strings available in comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql

As per official documentation, FIND_IN_SET returns the position of the first occurrence of string available from a comma-separated list. But I want to get the count of available string in a comma-separated list.

For example :

```
SELECT id, name, FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7') as num FROM users;
```

It returns the following result

```
+----+---------------+
| id | name    | num |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Jack    |   1 |
|  2 | Alex    |   3 |
|  3 | John    |   4 |
|  4 | Brett   |   5 |
|  5 | Keith   |   7 |
|  6 | Richard |   8 |
|  7 | Kent    |   9 |
+----+---------------+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eeacb/2

But I want the count of ids which matches the id of the table. So, the expected output should be like below.

```
SELECT id, name, SOME_FUNCTION(id, '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7') as num FROM users;

    +----+---------------+
    | id | name    | num |
    +----+---------------+
    |  1 | Jack    |   2 |
    |  2 | Alex    |   1 |
    |  3 | John    |   1 |
    |  4 | Brett   |   2 |
    |  5 | Keith   |   1 |
    |  6 | Richard |   1 |
    |  7 | Kent    |   3 |
    +----+---------------+
```

Comment: How are you generating the comma separated list of `id` values?

Comment: It is PHP variable coming programmatically.

Comment: Well why not do the count in PHP using [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)?

Comment: I don't want to loop through all records. It is just an example with 5-7 records. I have 1000+ records in database

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just count the values in the string in PHP. Can you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What if I want to set the order on that field from SQL Only.

Comment: @Nick Check my query which is what the OP wants to do.  Maybe you can give a workaround in PHP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen array_count_values is the workaround for the question as it has been asked.

Comment: I know that array_count_values is the solution but better if we can do it using SQL Only.

Comment: I still don't get what this has to do with MySQL

Comment: I want the MySQL function by which we can count the number of occurrence of id in the comma-separated list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions tricks:

```
set @s = '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7';
select id, name,
  ceiling((length(@s) - length(trim(both ',' from replace(
    replace(concat(',', replace(@s, ',', ',,'), ','), concat(',', id, ',' ), ''),
    ',,', ','
  )))) / (length(id) + 1)) as num
from users
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=0788b16038e2423e531633b85a9bc4bd)(with other possible cases).
Results:

```
id | name    | num
 1 | Jack    | 2
 2 | Alex    | 1
 3 | John    | 1
 4 | Brett   | 2
 5 | Keith   | 1
 6 | Richard | 1
 7 | Kent    | 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to move away from the CSV paradigm, and instead get the set of `id`s to match into its own table:

```
CREATE TABLE ids (id int);
INSERT INTO ids (id)
VALUES (1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(6),(7),(7),(7);
```

Then use the following simple query:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    COUNT(i.id) AS num
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN ids i
    ON u.id = i.id
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u.name;
```

Comment: This can be the solution but those ids are coming from PHP variable programmatically. I can't create a table.

Comment: Then maybe you need to query `users` and, for each record, determine the overlap count against your CSV string.

Comment: Do you mean loop through each user record?

Comment: @VivekPipaliya can you please edit your question with the relevant piece of PHP code so we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I don't want any PHP solution, I just want SQL solution. You can just consider those ids as dynamic

Comment: You can't easily do this in MySQL without using something like my answer, or writing a stored procedure.  So, handling in PHP might be your best option.

Comment: Stored function or Store procedure will be a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the comparison values as a string.  You can do some string tricks to count the number of values within the string and then add that up:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM( (LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', ids, ','), u.id, CONCAT(u.id, 'X'))) -
             LENGTH(CONCAT(',', ids, ','))
            ) 
          )
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7' as ids) x
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, x.ids) > 0
GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```

Note:  I created the subquery `x` as a convenience, so I can refer to `ids`.  You can pass in the value as a parameter instead:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       COUNT(*),
       SUM( (LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', ?, ','), u.id, CONCAT(u.id, 'X'))) -
             LENGTH(CONCAT(',', ?, ','))
            ) 
          )
FROM users u 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, ?) > 0
GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```